# Не работает эмуляция клавиатуры с RobotJS/Nut-JS и другими средствами нативной автоматизации

Tags: node.js, winapi, native, uiautomation

При попытке симулировать набор текста с клавиатуры, он или не набирается, или набираются другие символы.

- Как пример для пакета **sendkeys** набирается `89 9 ,38/,/` вместо
  `this is synchronous` (из примеров пакета)
- **RobotJS** - нещадно нажимает `Alt` `Ctrl` `Shift` при каждом «наборе», но сами символы не набираются.
- **Nut-JS** - тоже не работает.

Проблема наблюдается на обоих моих пк, причем как на Windows 7, так и на Windows 10.

Версии пакетов последние. Версия Node на Win7 и Win10 - **v15.4.0**

После запуска примеров ниже, есть **3000 мс** для переключение в какое либо текстовое поле куда оно будет набирать текст.

В первую очередь я заинтересован в **RobotJS**, но устроит решение на любом их данных пакетов.

Результат работы каждого скрипта должен быть - qwerty12345678Абвгд

**RobotJS**:

```js
const robot = require("robotjs");
 
setTimeout(() => {
    robot.typeString("qwerty");
    robot.typeString("12345678");
    robot.typeString("Абвгд");
}, 3000);
```

**NutJS**:

```js
const { keyboard, Key, mouse, left, right, up, down, screen } = require("@nut-tree/nut-js");

setTimeout(async() => {
    await keyboard.type("qwerty");
    await keyboard.type("12345678");
    await keyboard.type("Абвгд");
}, 3000);
```

**Sendkeys**:

```js
const sendkeys = require('sendkeys')
setTimeout(() => {
    sendkeys.sync("qwerty");
    sendkeys.sync("12345678");
    sendkeys.sync("Абвгд");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: ок, секунду. сейчас отредактирую

Comment: Дополнил вопрос кодом

Comment: норм. теперь можно и по делу: а к чему рассматривать NutJS и Sendkeys - модули, которые 100 лет не обновлялись и никем не используются?

Comment: Ну там вроде обертки winapi и обновлять нечего, если все рабоатет. Их я написал в связи с тем что у всех модулей одна и та же проблема. И попытка применить любой из них ни к чему не ведёт. Но меня конечно в первую очередь интересует RobotJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С `RobotJS` имел похожую проблему. Должна быть включена английская раскладка клавиатуры и тогда будет отлично печататся... только английский текст. Кирилицу заставить работать у меня не получилось.

Как вариант, записывайте инфу в буфер обмена (через соответствующую библиотеку) и потом <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>